# Arithmetic and harmonic mean of two numbers.

Tags: means

What is the maximum value of arithmetic mean of two integer number if their harmonic mean is 40?

$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} = \frac{2}{40}$$
$$xy=20x+20y$$
$$xy−20x−20y+20⋅20=400$$
$$(x−20)(y−20)=400$$

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} = \frac{2}{40}$ then $(x-20)(y-20)=400$

Comment: @Javi can you help me?

Comment: Sure. From that point (I'm assuming you've done the calculations properly), you can express $y$ as a function $f(x)$. Thus, compute the arithmetic mean in terms of $x$, and finally you can optimize that expression.

Comment: @Javi thanks it's a nice way, but I need solution without derivatives

Comment: Well, you didn't said anything about that, I'll have to think about it. Maybe you could find it graphically, but I guess you're expecting something more rigorous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} = \frac{2}{40}$$
$$xy=20x+20y$$
$$xy−20x−20y+20⋅20=400$$
$$(x−20)(y−20)=400$$
$400=1\cdot 400 =2\cdot 200 =4\cdot 100=5\cdot 80 = 8\cdot 50= 10\cdot 40=16\cdot 25=20\cdot 20$
$$ x+y = \{21+420; \;22+220;\;24+120;\;25+100;\;28+70;\;30+60;\;36+45;\;40+40\}
$$ 
the maximum value of summ is 441 and arithmetic mean is 220.5